# Find a lower bound of $k$ when $m!=100x^2+20x$ and $k*100x^2+20x=(m+5)!$

Tags: number-theory, approximation, factorial, upper-lower-bounds

$x$ & $m$ & $k$   are all real non-negative numbers. (Not necessarily intergers)

I have the equation:
$m!=100x^2+20x$

$100x^2+20x\neq (m+5)!$

$k*100x^2+20x=(m+5)!$
Can some one write a lower bound  of an approximation for $k$ using $x$ and/or $m$.

Comment: What do you mean by $m!$ when $m$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Servaes I think he means the [Pi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function).

Comment: @servaes the gamma function

Comment: @PintOfMilk The gamma function isn't factorial...

Comment: @ericw31415 thanks yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$(m+5)!=m! × (m+1)(m+2)(m+3)(m+4)(m+5)$$
$$k=(m+1)(m+2)(m+3)(m+4)(m+5)$$
 or by  estimation $ k>m^5$